# Get all urls ending in -2 in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I want to redirect all of the URLs of my application ending on `-2` to a specific action, I have a list of them but I don't want to make a different call to `routes.MapRoute()` for every different URL ending on `-2`. Instead, I want to use a regular expression to map them to that specific action, I don't have a great experience with Regular Expressions. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            "OldUrls",
            "{*path}",
            new { controller = "Redirect", action = "RedirectToUrl" },
            new { path = @".*-2"},
            new[] { "Application.Controllers" });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is find strings that ends with `-2` you don't even need `Regex`.

Just do:

```
if (url.EndsWith("-2"))
{

}
```

If you must use a `Regex`, then,

```
path = @".*-2$"
```

**Explanation:**

- `.*` = Zero or more characters.
- `-2` = Matches exactly `-2`.
- `$` = Matches the end of string.

**Also:**

It's advisable to use

```
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(YourURLString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
```

to validate your URL if it's never validated.